# MongoDb and Nodejs Server Response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, restify

In my javascript class, i have a function that return a list of things like so,

```
//ProjectClass.js
getProjectList: () =>
    @Project.find (err, projects) =>
        console.log(projects)
        return projects
```

However, whenever I try to send a server response from nodejs

```
//App.js
project = new projectSchema.Project()
res.send(project.getProjectList())
```

I get the following as a response

```
{
    "options": {
        "populate": {}
    },
    "_conditions": {},
    "_updateArg": {},
    "op": "find"
}
```

Ironically, if I pass the res object to my getProjectList and send server response from my getProjectList function then everything works just fine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Project.find` is an asynchronous function, calling your anonymous callback once the `find` results are available.  `getProjectList` returns the result of the last synchronous statement executed in that function which is the return value of `@Project.find`.  That's not the `projects` array your callback returns but the query object you see in your response.